# What is the formula for calculating an average rating from ratings originated from different sources?

Tags: web, average, formula, rating

I want to build a website, where I will show ratings for movies. I want to show there an average rating for a movie and I want to calculate that average from ratings from different sources. The issue is that on some of the desired sources a few people have rated a movie and in other sources thousands of them.   E.g. The movie "The Revenant". It has an average rating of 7.9 in IMDB (10000 users have voted) and it also has a 9.9 in "XYZ" website (10 users have voted). How would look like a formula in order to calculate that average?

Initially I thought of just simply assigning weights based on the number of users, but I have the feeling I am missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

average = sum_of(rating + number_of_people)/total_sum_of_people

Comment: What is number_of_people and total_sum_of_people? Is it the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make every vote weight the same then you should weight your averages by vote, as you initially thought. Formulae would be `(9.9 * 10 + 7.8 * 10k) / 10010`. You can however weight users from some sites more than others, using arbitrary weights.

Finally, note that computing algorithm for average is better done using an accumulator, in terms of memory and avoiding overflows (if that matters).

```
acc = scores[0]; u = users[0];
for (i = 1; i < nb_sites; i++)
    r = u / (u + users[i])
    acc = acc * r + users[i] * (1 - r)
    u += users[i] 
return acc
```